# javaFX Obfuscate error at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Tags: javafx, proguard, obfuscation

I'm new to JavaFX. I get this error when I try to run my JavaFX app

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javafx.application.Application.start(Ljavafx/stage/Stage;)V
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    ... 1 more
```

My main class is main.mainpage

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class mainpage extends Application {
    public static Stage STAGE;
    public static Scene SCENE;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        STAGE = stage;
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
    
        SCENE = new Scene(root);
        STAGE.setScene(SCENE);
        STAGE.show();

        STAGE.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
                Platform.exit();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Proguard config file:

```
-injars '************************************************************.jar'
-outjars '************************************************************-obf.jar'

-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\lib\rt.jar'

-dontshrink
-obfuscationdictionary OBF.txt
-classobfuscationdictionary OBF.txt
-packageobfuscationdictionary OBF.txt
-dontnote
-dontwarn
-ignorewarnings


# Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their 'main'
# methods.
-keepclasseswithmembers public class com.javafx.main.Main, main.mainpage {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Rename FXML files together with related views
-adaptresourcefilenames **.fxml,**.png,**.css
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.fxml
-adaptclassstrings

# Save meta-data for stack traces
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# Keep all annotations and meta-data
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature,EnclosingMethod

# Keep names of fields marked with @FXML attribute
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @javafx.fxml.FXML *;
}

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
# enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}


# Also keep - Database drivers. Keep all implementations of java.sql.Driver.
-keep class * extends java.sql.Driver

# Keep names - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.
-keepclasseswithmembers,includedescriptorclasses,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

I use exe4j to make exe file. When I run without obfuscating then the app is working. But it doesn't work after obfuscating.

Comment: I don't use proguard, so I don't know how to do this, but you want to avoid obfuscating the name of the `start()` method, which is called by reflection when you call `launch(...)`. What's happening here, apparently, is proguard is changing the name of that method, so the `start()` method that is found by reflection is the one inherited from `Application`, which is abstract.

Comment: What do you use?? this Proguard is killing me

Comment: I don't obfuscate my code.

Comment: Tried your suggestion and it worked! thanx a lot